# Pug Autocompiler in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, pug

I am looking for a Pug autocompiler that works much like the SASS one. I am using VSCode and have found a great SASS auto-compiler, but I still need one for Pug.

Comment: I have been working on a Pug Auto Compiler extension myself. It's work in progress, but I've tested it in on OSX by placing the code inside the extensions folder and it works fine. It watches for files with a .pug extension and it auto-compiles them to HTML. The code is based on a similar extension which auto compiles TypeScript files to JS. You can take a look at the code and check it on your system: https://github.com/kostasx/vscode-pug-compiler

Comment: There is no wider use case for this. It's a classic beginner confusion about what tools to use for what (which is fine). Pug is a templating language and as such there's really no point in using it statically.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using **Live Pug Compiler** extension (5 stars). Compile PUG files to HTML at real time with this extension. It works very well.